# Knn distance plot for determining eps of DBSCAN

Tags: python, clustering, parameter-estimation, dbscan

I would like to use the knn distance plot to be able to figure out which eps value should I choose for the DBSCAN algorithm.
Based on [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/dbscan-density-based-clustering-for-discovering-clusters-in-large-datasets-with-noise-unsupervised-machine-learning) page:

> The idea is to calculate, the average of the distances of every point
>   to its k nearest neighbors.  The value of k will be specified by the
>   user and corresponds to MinPts. Next, these k-distances are plotted in
>   an ascending order. The aim is to determine the “knee”, which
>   corresponds to the optimal eps parameter.

Using python with numpy/sklearn, I have the following points, with the following distance for 6-knn:

```
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=len(X)).fit(X)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)

# Indices

[[0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [1 0 2 3 4 5]
 [2 1 0 3 4 5]
 [3 4 5 0 1 2]
 [4 3 5 0 1 2]
 [5 4 3 0 1 2]]

# Distances
[[ 0.          1.          2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  5.        ]
[ 0.          1.          1.41421356  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.83095189]
[ 0.          1.41421356  2.23606798  5.          5.83095189  7.21110255]
[ 0.          1.          2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  5.        ]
[ 0.          1.          1.41421356  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.83095189]
[ 0.          1.41421356  2.23606798  5.          5.83095189  7.21110255]]
```

then I computed the average distance:

```
distances.mean()
2.9269575028354495
```

The problem is I don't understand how exactly could I represent the same plot as them with distances in y-axis and number of points according to the distances on the x-axis using python.

Thank for your help.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFDbs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFDbs.png) Why does my neighboring point graph have this shape?
Please help me!!!

Comment: See also [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48594371/3342058](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48594371/3342058)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You

1. take the last column of that matrix
2. sort descending
3. plot index, distance
4. hope to see a knee (if the distance does not work well. there might be none)

Comment: On the same plot, I do this for different k? or only one k for one plot as in the example? and what do you mean by "index"

Comment: Using the 6NN when you only have 6 points is of course nonsense. Do it for an appropriate k. Index as in "array index". because you need 2d to plot.

Comment: And i only use the last column of the distance matrix. Because in the example they talk about averaging distances..

Comment: That post is incorrect there *and* in at least another place (you don't need to set a seed)

Comment: Okey. Just one last thing, you seem to tell me that I have to make a plot for each k right? Cause here: https://github.com/alitouka/spark_dbscan/wiki/Choosing-parameters-of-DBSCAN-algorithm it seems different to what you say no? Thx

Comment: You only have one k. Why don't you use the DBSCAN paper. but mash-up various low-quality websites?